# MUI Dialog does not allow select an option of Blockly component with multiple choices

Tags: material-ui, blockly

I'm using a dialog to display a blocky based workspace, but I found that input blocks were not editable. For example, I was not able to type something in a `text` block neither select an option of component with multiple choices (e.g., `logic_compare`, `math_arithmetic`).

[image]

I was able to fix the issue with text input components by setting the property `disableEnforceFocus` of the Dialog to `true`, but the problem persists for the input blocks with multiple choices.

```
<Dialog
   ...
   disableEnforceFocus
>
...
</Dialog>
```

I tried every other property [Modal property](https://mui.com/api/modal/#props) without success to solve the second problem :(

Here you can find an example that reproduce the described problem

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-booth-w18h4

Any suggestion how to solve it?

Comment: Code should be in the question itself as a [mcve], not a sandbox link, which can disappear over time rendering the question useless to future visitors. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the issue with multiple choice input blocks: z-index.

After changed the z-index for the `blocklyDropDownDiv` the problem was gone.

Add the following CSS and that's it

```
.blocklyDropDownDiv {
    z-index: 5000;
}
```